# Troubleshooting my PS3

Tags: technical-issues, ps3

My PS3 Slim CECH-2501a was having some trouble, I think with overheating, so I popped it open with the help of ifixit's tutorial and cleaned it. After putting it back together however, I started having some problems. At first it gave me the red light indicating it was getting power, but not active. If I pushed the power button it would flicker green then go out completely.

Pulling the PSU to ensure everything was properly plugged in, it was, I put the PSU back and tried again. It turned on this time. I figured the problem was gone, so I unplugged it and put the screws I hadn't bothered with back in, specifically the torx security screws. Then the problem reappeared. Agitated I removed the torx screws and tried again, figuring I didn't care if they were out if my system worked, but it didn't do anything one way or another. A bit of online research and I decided to ensure my fingerprint oils hadn't gotten on the ribbon contacts, so I gently wiped a q-tip with alcohol over them to clean them.

That didn't work either. So I went on ifixit's Q/A site to get an answer. Only got one response, someone suggesting the YLOD, but that doesn't make sense because it's not giving my a yellow light at all.

Please help me fix my PS3.

Update: Got a new PSU and installed it, new PSU had the same problem. Leaves me to wonder if I might be somehow putting the PSU in incorrectly.